# Adding an object to an array using mongoose if value not found, otherwise updating fields

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to handle MongoDB.

I have the following document

```
Posts:Array
    0:Object
        _id:58f9b2c903110b2c543fb7d1
        postName:Test1
        postText:Test2
        postCount:0
        status:true
```

I would like to do a HTTP request to update or insert an object to this array based on postName.

for example, if I pass the following

```
{
    postName:Test1
    postText:Test3
    postCount:50
    status:false
}
```

Than postName matches and I would like it to just update postText, postCount and status.
If postName does not matches any one of the objects in the array, I would like it to insert a new object.

This question maybe duplicate to old questions, I searched and I couldn't find the answer.
I also tried to use $setOnInsert but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Use this  `db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: true
   }
)`

Comment: What is <update>? how can I make it be based on postName? Thanks

Comment: db.collection.update({postName:Test1}, {
    postName:Test1
    postText:Test3
    postCount:50
    status:false
}, { upsert: true } )

Comment: I understand, can I do this update on a query? for example db.collection.findOne({ _id: id }).update(...) so I'll do it on a specific document?

Comment: refer this link  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate

Comment: I'm familiar with this API, however, how can I query both for the document id and postName field in its array?

Comment: Upsetting into embedded array documents is not possible in a single query.Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112403/pymongo-update-document-with-multiple-records/41113069#41113069

Comment: Thanks, looks good but I have an issue with that. I get the document id from the session field which is in the request (HTTP request). I can do the first step in the upserting but I don't have the request in the scope of the call back function to do the push if neccessery, do you know how I can handle that? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I guess I do have it if I use it in the callback... didn't know that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As Veeram replied in the comments,

The answer can be found here

[PyMongo Update document with multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112403/pymongo-update-document-with-multiple-records/41113069#41113069)

Upsetting into embedded array documents is not possible in a single query